# Update Bulk Data in Mongodb

Tags: performance, mongoose, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I have **50k users** in my collection, I want to add a new field suppose `rowNumber` to every record, i tried this solution using `cursor`, but it is taking too much time, so how can i increase performance or what will be the better approach?

```
  let user, cursor, rowNumber = 1;
  cursor = User.aggregate().cursor({ batchSize: 10 }).exec();
  while ((user = await cursor.next())) {
    let savedUser = await User.updateOne(
      {  _id: user._id },
      { $set: { rowNumber: rowNumber++ } }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has a `bulkWrite` functionality just for that purpose.

```js
const users = await User.find().exec();
const writeOperations = users.map((user, i) => {
  return {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: user._id },
      update: { rowNumber: i + 1 }
    }
  };
});

await User.bulkWrite(writeOperations);
```