# Smart way to update all documents in mongodb using python function

Tags: pymongo

I execute `some_python_function` on all elements of collection.
This function returns different values for each document.

I developed the following function, but it's very slow.

```py
for doc in db.collection.find(query, projection):
    result = db.collection.update_one(
        {"_id": doc["_id"]}, 
        {"$set": {"field": some_python_function(doc["field"])}}
    )
```

I am looking any smarter way to do it, rather than updating documents one-by-one.

What would you recommend?

**EDIT:**
I have just found bulk operations in the API:
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne

updates = []
for doc in db.collection.find(filter, projection):
    if doc.get("titles"):
        updated_field = some_python_function(doc["field"])
        if doc["field"] != updated_field:
            updates.append(
                UpdateOne(
                    {"_id": doc["_id"]}, 
                    {"$set": {"field": updated_field)}}
                )
            )
if updates:
    result = collection.bulk_write(updates)
```

Comment: Is `some_python_function` simple enough so that the MongoDB server could implement it with its typical operators, or with a `javascript` `"$function"`?  If so, perhaps having the server calculate `"field"` might be faster since it will eliminate most of the IO.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case, but `some_python_function` is quite complex, uses external libraries etc.

Comment: Just wondering... Since only `"field"` is used to update `"field"`, is there any way to verify the `some_python_function` transformation has occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bulkWrite](https://ttps://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html) to write multiples document at once.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230298/update-bulk-data-in-mongodb) for a similar question.